# Printing Python code on html file

Tags: python, html, printing, echo

I have a really noob question here , in php if u wanted to print something inside html you did something like this

```
<body>
<div>
<?
echo 'Hi i am inside of a div';
?>
</div>
</body>
```

How do i do that in python?

Comment: you can also pass a dict using  `html.format(**d)` for multiple placeholders.

Answer (score 3):

In a simple case you can use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting). Put a placeholder into the string and use [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) to substitute the placeholder with the actual text:

```
html = """
<body>
<div>
{text}
</div>
</body>
"""

print html.format(text='Hi i am inside of a div')
```

In case of complex HTML structures, you can make use of template languages, like [`jinja2`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/). You would basically have an html template which you would render with the context provided:

```
import jinja2

env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('.'))
template = env.get_template('index.html')
print template.render(text='Hi i am inside of a div')
```

where `index.html` contains:

```
<body>
    <div>
    {{ text }}
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: what if i have complex templates ?

Comment: @Maks if you have complex templates you should look in to using a Web framework like flask, Django or pyramid.

Comment: I've been searching and it seems u can use <% ** PYTHON CODE HERE ** %> , but it doesnt seem the work with me